# Setting tooltip opacity

Tags: leaflet

Is there a way to set the opacity of a tooltip after it's created?

I expected Marker.setOpacity(0) on the Marker to change the opacity of the tooltip too but it does not, I can't find any reference to it in the current documentation but the older documentation for https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.label does suggest *You can set the opacity of a label by calling the setOpacity method on L.Marker.*

However, it seems this does not work in recent versions of leaflet?

Comment: Is leaflet a JS lib? perhaps add JavaScript tag to increase the views/potential help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `setOpacity` directly on the tooltip object.

To access it from the marker call:

```
marker.getTooltip().setOpacity(0.2);
```